# How to make some value sliders of a node in a node group display on the group node

Tags: node-editor

I made my first node group , now i want the node group to display some fields inside it on the node itself , how do i do that.

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176247/86891

Answer (score 1):

Use some nodes with sliders (for example a Map Range Node) on it and connect it to the hollow group input or node as seen in this screen shot.
[image]

After that use the N-Panel to set up the minumum and maximum slider range.

The Result looks like this:
[image]